# Trichloroacetic acid aqueous solution

Tags: acid-base, aqueous-solution, solutions

I have bought some <s>anhydride of</s> trichloroacetic acid ([TCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichloroacetic_acid)) and would like to prepare an acidic solution. My problem is, that I don't know how much "powder" to mix with how much water to produce an x% acidic solution of TCA.  I am aiming for as close to 100% as possible. From what I know, I need to measure pH to derive the concentration (I only have some litmus paper to do that)? Does there exist formulas or tables, that I can follow? Sources of these?

EDIT: Based on a comment, I obtained these values:

I have bought 1 kg of TCA powder of

```
1000 g / 163.38 gmol^-1 = 6.1207 mol
18.01528 gmol^-1 * 6.1207 mol = 110.27 g of water
```

somehow I need to dissolve 1 kg of powder into 110.27 mL of water. How can that work? I doubt 1 kg of powder can be dissolved in such a tiny amount of water.

EDIT2: Wikipedia says `Solubility in water: Soluble in 0.1 parts`. Does this mean I need `0.1 * TCA amount` for a 100% solution? That would mean I need to dissolve 1 kg of TCA in 100 mL of water.

EDIT3: If you have any idea about the true solubility of TCA, please help,  there seems to be a lot of misinformation out there. 1000 g / 100 mL seems very strange to me! You can see the strange data [here](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/trichloroacetic_acid#section=Solubility), from multiple sources.

EDIT4: I have asked my Chinese supplier about how they prepare their TCA solution and he said they use 120g - 154.1g / 100 mL recipe for a "standard" solution. The concentration can then be calculated by mole or by mass, but naturally is never 100%. The only way a 100% liquid TCA could exist would be to melt it down into liquid form.

Comment: Dig around online for preparing stock solutions. From what I have seen 6.1N TCA is ~100% w/v. So look up how to prepare solutions using Normal or Equivalents of a reagent. I believe since TCA is mono protic 6.1N ~ 6.1M however I dont do wet chemistry anymore - so I'd have to let someone else give you a proper answer.

Comment: @Mithoron I guess the idea is, that all the molecules of the anhydride react with all the molecules of water? Where can I get the molar mass of the anhydride?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's just a matter of calculating how many moles of anhydride you have and (carefully and slowly) adding same amount of water. Be careful as anhydride may be dangerous itself and reaction vigorous.

Comment: @Mithoron I calculated I get 110 mL of 100% acid for 1 kg of powder, I find that unbelievable. 1000 g / 163.38 gmol^-1 = 6.1207 mol, 6.1207 mol * 18.01528 gmol^-1 = 110.27 g (mL). That's such a tiny amount for 1 kg of powder. How can I pour 1 kilo into 110 mL of water, seems bizarre?

Comment: You should add it to question - edit it, otherwise it may be put on hold. Molar mass of water is much smaller so values seems reasonable, but may be somewhat problematic ;) That's another thing worth asking in body of question.

Comment: @Mithoron It seems to me you have provided a correct answer to a wrong question. My question is incorrect. What I have bought is actually TCA, not its anhydride. An anhydride would probably fume all the time, but what I have merely stinks terribly. TCA is a solid. Can I salvage my question somehow? I need to prepare a 100% solution out of a solid and water.